# Localizing month names simple_form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date, datetime, internationalization, simple-form

I'm using simple_form and when the input is a date, I do:

```
<%= f.input :start_date, :label => t('start_date'), :as => :date, :start_year => Date.today.year - 90,
                              :end_year => Date.today.year, :discard_day => true,
                              :order => [:month, :year] %>
```

However, the month names are not correct to my locale. How do I change the localization file in order to get the correct names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You DID get your standard rails locale from https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale ?

Comment: No. But thanks for the link: this way I know how to alter my localization file.

Comment: how did you achieve it?